# HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, http-error

I have problem like

```
HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request
ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL.
```

... when requesting the following URL:

```
http://hunarmandindia.com/(S(4wuduaje2xivjefwffjv5bgq))/Company/recruiter-login.aspx
```

If anyone can have any solution about this problem please give me solution...

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of characters that are prevented by IIS/ASP.NET by default in a URL as they are a telltale sign of someone trying to perform certain attacks on your site.  You can disable or loosen these checks, as described here (http://dirk.net/2008/06/09/ampersand-the-request-url-in-iis7/) for example, but before you go ahead and do that, I'd first check whether you truly need the invalid characters that are being used (likely ones are ampersands, angle brackets, the word 'script' etc. but it's hard to tell without seeing the URL in question), as loosening these rules obviously opens you up to the attacks this feature is trying to prevent.

Comment: Advice is the same.  Brackets are the restricted characters in this case.  Check out this blog post by Scott Hanselman for more info and how to relax the validation, just be aware, as I said above, that doing so will open you up to potential attacks (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx).  Ideally, I'd prefer to remove the brackets from the URL if it was me.  Can't see any obvious reason why you'd need them.

Comment: Setting ValidateRequest to false in your web.config disables this check completely, so it's best to check that you're putting it in the right place etc. based on the articles above.  Other than that, as I've said a couple of times above, the much simpler (and secure) way is to remove the need for brackets in your URL route.  That's the real solution to this issue.